# How to override device pixel ratio

Tags: css, google-chrome, responsive-design, resolution, pixel-ratio

I made a responsive website which works fine with different screen resolutions. I use three different media queries - from 0 to 640, from 640 to 960 and above. Anyway if I try to open on my Samsung Galaxy Note2 which uses 720x1280,  since it has pixel ratio 2, it reads the website as 360x640 device, but with 640-960 styles.

How can I be sure that the website will be displayed in original resolution?

I included this in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

If I add something like this in my stylesheet file

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
@viewport {
     max-zoom:50%;
     width:720px;
}
}
```

It works OK in Chrome's Emulation Mode, but not if I test it on the real mobile.

**EDIT:** Woo-hoo... I found a way to do that with JavaScript.

```
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale='+(1/window.devicePixelRatio)+', maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');
```

It reads device pixel ratio and then sets the `initial-scale` value.

Comment: This....`maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"` is not recommended. It's just poor user experience.

Comment: @Paulie_D      I know, but the website is made that zooming shouldn't be the good idea and basically cannot be avoided.

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for. Calling that javascript can be done, if the user wants to show the screen as seen in the desktop. Very helpful at times.

Answer (score 4):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
  </head>
  <script>
        function toggleZoomScreen() {
        document.body.style.zoom = (1 / window.devicePixelRatio);
        }
    </script>
  <body onload="toggleZoomScreen()" onresize="toggleZoomScreen()">
    <p>This is an example paragraph. Anything in the <strong>body</strong> tag will appear on the page, just like this <strong>p</strong> tag and its contents.</p>
`<img src="https://c.tenor.com/xlylHMRf90oAAAAj/funny-face.gif" width="50">`
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's an example that keeps the same size no matter the device's Pixel Ratio. (thanks to [@chrisvfritz](https://gist.github.com/chrisvfritz/) on Github for the [simplest possible HTML template.](https://gist.github.com/chrisvfritz/bc010e6ed25b802da7eb))

When the document is loaded, it runs the script above, which sets the body's zoom to 1 divided by the device's pixel ratio, resulting in text and images being 1:1 scale.

**PROS:** Tested on different device scaling, works well.

**CONS:** Zoom does not work.

Comment: This helped me a lot. Although one should be careful with hijacking the zoom functionality in regards to accessibility, if this fixes the UI and makes it in general usable again (whereas a 150% OS Zoom would break it entirely), I think it's absolutely fine to do so. Browser Zooming is still possible, though. But: Attention to Bootstrap grid classes, they will be hijacked as well, e.g. small grid classes are triggered on (then emulated) bigger viewport sizes. I'm sure there's also a workaround somewhere around for this.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but try changing:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Setting the width to 720 would explain why your 640-960 styles are being applied.