# how to resolve website zoom to 150% in windows 10 by default

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-10, zooming

I am working on a website which is working normally on 100% zoom level.

but in some windows laptops  the recomended zoom level 150%, so  website is zoomed and some sections overlapping in 150%.

however when we change the zoom level to 100% in windows settings website looks normal.

> 1. could anyone tell the right approach to handle this issue ?
> 2. Is there any way yto target and change windows zoom level to 100% ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
window.devicePixelRatio
```

to detect odd zoom percentages. Here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209628/how-to-override-device-pixel-ratio) to where someone asked a similar question. I'm not sure where you would go next. Maybe you'd increase the padding by that percentage or something

**EDIT:** Person in the link said this worked:

```
document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale='+(1/window.devicePixelRatio)+', maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0')
```