# how to adapt website view for users with Widows zoom 150%

Tags: css, vue.js, google-chrome, responsive-design, responsive

In the company I work, people receive laptops with default zoom 150%. Most of users change it immediately, but some older people keep zoom 150% for convinience.

I'm building Vue3 app interface and I came accross issue with responsivenes.  The browser resolution could be HD 1920x1024 but zoom is 150%.

I started my research here:
[How to override device pixel ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24209628/how-to-override-device-pixel-ratio)

I wonder is it general solution for my index meta or could it be decicated for Vue3?

Can anybody guide me in solutions which provide fine UI look for users using zoom 150%.

Comment: You should not overwrite DPR but leave the control to the user. Rather implement an RWD that is not fixed on certain resolutions but rather cares for different viewport widths. Also always use em or rem as values for font sizes that still allow users to change the size through the windows or browser settings as they like or need. If you take that away you will hurt UX.